# Highcharts event handler after finishing redraw

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to show the total of the Y axis as a subtitle for a HighStock chart.
This is initially accomplished by summing up the point.y value of all the series, inside the "load" event like so:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () {
            var chart = this,
                series = chart.series,
                seriesSum = 0;
            series.forEach(function (series) {
                series.data.forEach(function (point) {
                    seriesSum += point.y
                })
            })
            this.update({
                subtitle: { text: 'TOTAL:  ' + seriesSum }
            });
        },
    }
}
```

Now I need to update the TOTAL amount after the chart has been redrawn after changing the timeframe using either the Navigator or the Range Selector. I know there is a "redraw" event, but that will end me up in an infinite loop. Which event should I be tack onto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`redraw`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw) event, and just not redraw within a pending redraw. For example:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        redraw: function () {
            this.update({
                subtitle: { text: 'TOTAL:  ' + seriesSum }
            }, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `false` parameter to the [`Chart.update`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update) function to prevent further redrawing (infinite loop).

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3spo68j0/1/) using Highcharts and the `redraw` event.

Comment: Thanks and that takes care of the infinite loop. 
Now the chart.series contains all of the initial series bound to the chart. How do I access the subset of the series that is presently in display so that subtotal is only pertaining to the active series set?

Comment: I've created the above question as as separate question, if anyone could answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357592/highcharts-accessing-zoomed-series-data

Comment: Seems like a separate issues, yes. I'll give it a look!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` method with `redraw` flag in `redraw` event, but you must set right conditions to not to fall into an infinite loop:

```
var redrawEnabled = true;

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        events: {
            redraw: function() {
                if (redrawEnabled) {
                    var sum = 0;
                    redrawEnabled = false;

                    Highcharts.each(this.series[0].points, function(point) {
                        if (point.isInside) {
                            sum += point.y;
                        }
                    });

                    this.update({
                        subtitle: {
                            text: sum
                        }
                    });

                    redrawEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dewumkz6/