# HighCharts: Accessing Zoomed Series Data

Tags: highcharts

If i zoom an HighStock multi series chart (using either the Navigator or the Range Selector), is there a way to fetch the point.y data only for the zoomed series?

For example, if I am showing the sales information for a period across multiple branches (each branch plotted as series), and if zoomed to a week, I would like to know the total of sales for the week across the branches. Does highstock provide access to the zoomed dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You can check `isInside` flag on every point:

```
        redraw: function() {
            var sum = 0;

            Highcharts.each(this.series[0].points, function(point) {
                if (point.isInside) {
                    sum += point.y;
                }
            });
            console.log(sum)
        }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7kmzhecy/

Comment: This doesnt work for highstock chart reliably (havent tried for hicharts alone), using Navigator or the Range Selector. I need to debug and see where its getting off.

Answer (score 0):

A very brute force approach to this is to loop over your data upon zooming and evaluate if it is visible. That is, is a given point within the range of the x-axis (and y-axis, if you allow zoom in that direction)?

```
chart: {
    events: {
        redraw: function() {
            sum = 0;
            xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
            // Loop over your series
            this.series[0].data.forEach(function(point) {
                // Add to sum if within x-axis visible range
                if(point.x >= xAxis.min && point.x <= xAxis.max) {
                    sum += point.y;
                }
                // If too large, stop summing
                if(point.x > xAxis.max) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            // Print sum
            console.log('Visible sum: '+sum);
        }
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/01ow2zec/) of it in use.

You might evaluate `xAxis.events.setExtremes`, but it offers `min` and `max` values that might change after it takes effect, which might give some unexpected results.

Comment: This seems like an unnecessarily expensive operation. Hopefully someone can bring something with better performance

Comment: Thanks Halvor, or may be we could just directly filter the series dataset for the zoom period and then sum it up. (which will not involve checking the point values) I will check that.